# Copying Row from a table to another another table, and stamp the date&time the row is copied over

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do the follow:

Sheet1 - Table1 (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD)

Sheet2 - Table2 (ColumnA, ColumnC, DateCopy)

If possible, I want to copy row from Table 1 to Table 2 where ColumnD is not null.

And Stamp the date&time in DateCopy.

One additional question if possible: when copy Row from Table1 to Table2, is it possible to not copy cell in Column B or have to copy the entire Row ?

This is my code:

```
Sub copyComments()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rowcount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim oLastRow As ListRow
    Dim srcRow As Range


    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    rowcount = tbl.ListRows.Count


    For i = 3 To rowcount

    If Cells(i, 3).Value <> vbNullString Then

    Set srcRow = tbl.ListRows(i - 2).Range

    Set oLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add

    srcRow.Copy

    oLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    End If

    Next
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try `oLastRow.Cells(0,oLastRow.Columns.Count).Value2 = Now()` for the timestamp.

Comment: Hi BigBen, Thank you for your comment. I have tried your, but it right before End If. But it returned Run-Time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.